# Getting Time Difference as Input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, time

How to get input as hours and minutes in HTML?

For example, a user has to enter the time taken to perform a particular task and it took them 2 hours and 45 minutes. How can I get this as a input using a single textbox.

If I use, `<input type="time">`, it includes `am/pm` which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.without::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
   display: none;
 }
 input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance:none;
   appearance: none;
   margin: -10px; 
 }

 <input type="time" class="without" />
```

But bear in mind this is for only browser using webkit you may have to check for other browsers.

This is not good for production, I would rather suggest you to use custom input type.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css:

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
  display: none;
}
```